# Differences between Invoke-Expression and Invoke-Expression -Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Can someone explain the differences between `Invoke-Expression $test` and `Invoke-Expression -Command $test`?

variable test is:

```
 $test = "notepad.exe myfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both `Invoke-Expression $test` and `Invoke-Expression -Command $test` are the same. Both will put `$test` into the 'command' parameter that is at position 1. The `-Command` is and optional parameter name that you can put in.

```
SYNTAX
    Invoke-Expression [-Command] <string> [<CommonParameters>]
```

Answer (score 5):

They're functionally equivalent. `-Command` is the only parameter the cmdlet takes that isn't in the `CommonParameters` set and the first one (by default, since it's the only one) when used positionally.

All you're doing with the second example is being explicit with naming your parameter, instead of relying upon position. That's a good habit to get into. Verbose, but future-proof and it makes your intention crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

Both are not same :

**[Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6)** : Runs commands or expressions on the local computer.

**[Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6)** : Runs commands on local and remote computers.

Answer (score -5):

The commands are similar but do behave differently. For instance:

```
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create( "test-path 'c:'")
iex $sb
icm $sb
```

The `iex` will produce error while `icm` will not.

Comment: `icm` stands for `invoke-command` and has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Invoke-expression -command, command is a flag to invoke-expression method, icm is calling invoke-command which is a different method completely